# retrieve id according to the class

Tags: javascript

I am working with a chatbot interface and I need to retrieve the message id and add it to the submit function. I attempted to use $(".msf-text").id, but it returned undefined. How can I  retrieve the id? It is important to note that there are multiple messages within the msg-text class, and I would like the submit function to contain the id of the submitted message.

```
randomeIndex = getRandomInt(100000000)
message_index = randomeIndex
<div class="msg-text" id="message-${message_index}">${text}</div>
```

```
    msgerForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
   
    
      const message_id = $(".msf-text").id
      console.log("message id is " + message_id)
}
```

Comment: `$(".msf-text")` returns a jquery object containing an array of all elements with the `msf-text` class. What you've done is basically like doing `[{id:0},{id:1}].id`. You have to select which element in that array you're trying to get the id of.

Comment: @JosephWebber I tried $(".msf-text")[0] and it's still undefined

Comment: I didn't realize you had a typo in your question (msf-text vs msg-text). Change it to `msg-text` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery::prop()` method to access a DOM property of the first element in a jQuery object:

https://api.jquery.com/prop/

(you made a type also `.msf-text` => `.msg-text`)

```
const message_id = $(".msg-text").prop('id');
```

Or (make sure the element exists):

```
const message_id = $(".msg-text")[0].id;
```

Comment: $(".msf-text")[0] is undefined, it's strange that it returns no element there, hmm

Comment: @Lucia you made a type, should be `.msg-text`

Comment: oh yes, the typo, $(".msg-text")[0].id return an empty string ' ' . But I can see the message id is in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You may consider not using jQuery. Here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
to retrieve the last element of a collection of specific elements.

```js
// assign id to all .msg-text for demo
document.querySelectorAll(`.msg-text`)
  .forEach((msg, i) => msg.id = `message-${i + 1}`);

// retrieve the last message id:
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(`.msg-text`)].pop().id);

// when the elements are embbeded in a root element
// (for demo this is the case)
// you can use the :last-child pseudo selector
console.log(document.querySelector(`.msg-text:last-child`).id);
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="msg-text">message 1</div>
  <div class="msg-text">message 2</div>
  <div class="msg-text">message 3</div>
  <div class="msg-text">message 4</div>
  <div class="msg-text">message 5</div>
  <div class="msg-text">message 8</div>
  <div class="msg-text">message 7</div>
</div>
```